# Character sums: reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This one will be quick...

Wonder if anybody knows or remembers the title of the paper in which Karatsuba *introduced* his approach at Burgess's bound on character sums.

Thanks for your support.

EDIT. It might have been in "Sums of characters and primitive roots in finite fields". Since this appeared in Russian in Dokl. Akad. Nauk. SSSR, would any of you guys be so kind as to provide us with a review of the translation that, according to MathSciNet, appeared in Soviet Math. Dokl. 9 (1968), 755–757? Thanks again.

**ADDED**. I've been trying to get a copy of the corresponding issue of the Soviet Mathematics Doklady in the libraries to which I have access (real or virtual). It all has been to no avail. Does any of you know if there is a possibility to get a copy of it through the AMS? I recently took at look at *ams.org* to find out, but I didn't find info regarding the acquisition of back issues of the said journal.

Comment: It really is not ok to ask for an explicit violation of copyright. Voting to close.

Comment: That is certainly a more reasonable request...

Comment: Guess this might be a nice example of a borderline case on the copyright theme. Anyways, I've edited the paragraph that seemed to antagonize the audience. Voting to re-open.


Answer (score 3):

The [Zentralblatt review](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an%3A0182.37501&format=complete) of the paper in the question, by J.J. Payan, seems to confirm OP's expectation (it is viewable without subscription). It says basically that new methods for the investigation of character sums and distribution of primitive roots are introduced and that results of Burgess (Proc LMS, 1962) are extended.

Answer (score 1):

This is [the review](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/karareview.pdf), which is not very informative, but there you have it.

Comment: Did you ask for permission to post this review? I mean there is an AMS  copyright notice on it. Or am I missing something? 

Comment: quid: The review is four lines long. It's virtually a tweet.

Comment: @Tom Leinster: I am not sure if this is so relevant. Not that *I* would care so much, but since Igor Rivin seems so strict on this matter (cf his comments on the question), I thought I point out to him that there is a potential problem. 

Comment: @quid: I am well aware that I am technically in breach of copyright. However, it is less of a breach than posting the whole paper, plus the AMS is less likely to complain than whichever shysters have the Doklady backlog these days.

Comment: Okay. And, if your less likely it not necessarily strict this should definitely be correct as after all for the translation I'd guess it is the AMS.
 

Comment: @quid: also, I have posted papers here in the past without being asked (since I am well aware that many people do not have access to the content), but if it becomes known that you can just go to MO and ask for copyrighted material and it will magically appear, we might be in deep doo-doo.